# Why does hyperlink in PDF not work on smartphones?

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I'm generating PDF reports using Jasper reports and I have hyperlink in generated file that doesn't work on smartphones when I open it using Adobe Acrobat Reader.

**Code to create the hyperlink**

```
<textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="450" y="80" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#0080FF" uuid="d11cac12-8769-450c-b9e8-f512179f33e3">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font size="10" isUnderline="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Go"]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["https://www.google.com"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: When hyperlink created in MS Word it works fine in my phone

Comment: I like this question, it would be nice if you manage to create a [mcve] a complete jrxml with complete example of java code used for export. If you need help ping me.

Comment: @Daniyar It is working for me fine (via *Kingsoft Office* on Android 4.4.2). Maybe it is depends on your application\settings on phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jaspersoft Studio, set the Link Target to ‘self’, it works for me. The Link Type is ‘Reference’.

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you! This should be accepted I think.